# impossible to install updates

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04

after installing APM Planner i had an updating problems
this what is showed when i try to install updates:

> E:The package apmplanner2:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't
>   find an archive for it.

Comment: How did you install APM Planer ?

Comment: I followed the instructions mensioned here http://ardupilot.org/planner2/docs/installation-for-linux.html